# Sending text from C# to Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, label

I know that i can send information to my C# classes using the x:name annotation in my XAML, but i wonder if there is something as easy as this, the other way around?

Like if i have a string in my C# code, that i just wanted to display in my view, say in a label box, would that be as easy?

Comment: The property name doesnt exist in label it says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  This is basic databinding

XAML:

```
<Label Text="{Binding MyTextProperty"} />
```

Code behind

```
public string MyTextProperty { get; set; }

this.BindingContext = this;
```

Comment: You forgot to add the fact that i need to set a bindingcontext.. Would have spared me some time :)

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this github example on dataBindings:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/DataBindingDemos

Basically you can bind any property of any xaml element to another c# class property.
Usually this is done following the MVVM model. So i'd recommend you read into that.

Binding makes it so that if the property changes on the XAML by user interaction it will reflect on the c# property and vice versa as long as the property is a Observable Collection Item.

So for instance if you have a class

```
class Foo : ObservableCollection{
    string a {get; set;}
}
```

And you do the steps to properly bind your xaml to the class described in the github above and the documentation below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/

You can go in your xaml file and do:

```
<Label Text = "{Binding a}" />
```

There are binding modes so you can define how the property change will interact, either one-way or two-way.